# app launch using custom scheme showing error in safari in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I tried to launch my native app from safari using custom scheme like `myapp://`.
This is working fine when app is installed, but when app is uninstalled ,safari is displaying:
 `page cannot found` popup .
My requirement is i need to redirect to some page,let's say apple store.
How to do this?
Any suggestions?

Is there any update on this?

Comment: The duplicate mark here is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, since the app handling the custom URL scheme is no longer available iOS does no longer know how to handle the custom URL.

Comment: whats the alternate of this? I guess Universal Links, is it right?

Comment: Yes my guess is that Universal Links might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and appending a question mark (?) at the end seems to resolve it. It was working fine till ios5 but needs this question mark since ioss 6.
While trying to launch you should say myapp://?parameter1=xyz

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for ur reply,but i m still getting "cannot open page because the address is invalid" error when app is uninstalled

Comment: i want to get rid of that popup and redirect to some other page in browser.any idea?